# In Jupyter notebook pyCarete predict_model (estimator) displays the metrics like MAE, RMSE in the cell, But not able to access it

Tags: pycaret

In Jupyter notebook pyCarete, predict_model (estimator) displays the metrics like MAE, RMSE in the cell, But is not able to access it. I need to assign it to a variable so I can use it in the future
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pull()` after any training function to return the scoring grid in `pandas.DataFrame` format. Then you can access specific data as usual in pandas.

Example to get the `MSE` value of your `predict_model()` call:

```
predict_model(...)
results = pull()
print(results.MSE[0])
```

Output:

```
34931120.0000
```